# find the line number in a file starting with a pattern from current line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How to find out the line number which starts with date in yyyy-mm-dd format from current line number? In the example below, i wanted to find out the line number of the line starts with **2016-10-09 gggg** from my current line no which is 10. There is no specific pattern for the lines after 10 till N+1 and these lines will not starts with a date. my current code is given below

```
lineNos=($(grep -n ERROR $file | cut -d':' -f1 | tail -3))
length=${#lineNos[@]} 
for((i=0;i<length;i++));do 
  lineNumber=${lineNos[i]}`
  endLineNo= Need to find this
 sed -n "${lineNumber},${endLineNo}p" $file
done
```

## example

```
    2016-10-04 mmm wewer
10  2016-10-09 ERROR ddddd
11  ttttt
12  errrrr
    ...
N   ...
N+1 2016-10-09 gggg
N+2 2016-10-10 mmm
```

Comment: Current line is similar to N+1 line. It starts with a date. I have got a grep command that gives me the current line number

Comment: This sounds like a classic X-Y problem - what is your overall goal (*before* you decided that it could be solved by searching forward from the "current" line number)?

Comment: I know current line no. If I could find the N+1 line no then I can cut the lines till N+1 for further processing

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) show us an example of *both* your input  files and ii) an example of the output you are expecting and iii) the command you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but please give *all* the information I asked for. That's your input, what output do you expect from that? And can there be more than one line matching `2016-10-09 gggg` in your file? What should happen if there is?

Answer (score 1):

This is classic task for awk, you probably don't need 'first grep':

```
cat myfile | awk '/pattern1/ {start=1} /pattern2/ {if (start) print NR}'
```

if you really want to find pattern2, but start searching only from line LINE, you could do:

```
cat myfile | awk '/pattern2/ {if (NR>'$LINE') print NR}'
```

Comment: This is what i have done so far  <pre>lineNos=($(grep -n ERROR $file | cut -d':' -f1 | tail -3))
length=${#lineNos[@]}
for((i=0;i<length;i++));do
lineNumber=${lineNos[i]}

endLineNo=

sed -n "${lineNumber},${endLineNo}p" $file

done

Answer (score 0):

```
offset=$(grep -n 'pattern1' /path/to/input | cut -d: -f1)
awkcmd="/pattern2/ { \$1 = \$1 - $offset; print \$0 }"
cat -n /path/to/input | awk "$awkcmd"
```